# Deleting data from data base with phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I need some non-technical help deleting lines in a Mysql database table. Started out doing so line-by-line using the REDX button.  While this was tiring it was working.  Then I accidentally hit that button to "not tell me this again" and now even that doesn't work.  I need to eliminate over 2,000 lines... can anyone help a non-techie like me? Please.

Comment: DELETE FROM table_name WHERE column = 'param';

Comment: I suggest you edit your questions title. There is no such thing as a "phpMySQL data base"...

Comment: @arkascha I suspect he meant phpMyAdmin, I've updated it accordingly.

Comment: See https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/q-zn-esdKd8 for how to re-enable confirmation popups in Chrome.

Comment: My apologies for the wrong title - as I said I am totally non-technical.  I (female) looked at the page and Barmar is correct phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have access to PHPMyAdmin, you can click on the desired database name, then look for a tab "SQL" - the following query will delete anything from the table that matches the parameter passed:

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE column = 'param';
```

You would replace `table_name` with the name of the table you want to delete from, `column` with what you want to match data on, and `param` with what to match.

So for example

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE email = 'test@example.com';
```

I feel like this is the most basic and non-technical way I can put it.

Comment: Thank you for your help Adam and Barmar - this fixed it for me.

Comment: Awesome, when you can, accept an answer if it resolves the problem for you. This will help keep you in good standing for future questions :)